# C++ connect function error - Invalid argument

Tags: c++, sockets, arguments, connect

I'm trying to make a simple socket client (using debian 6 and g++ compiler) and when I'm calling "connect" function, it returns error code 22 - Invalid argument. Tell me, what am I doing wrong, please.

I've read the man page for this function and it says that the 3 arguments must be as followed: int, struct sockaddr* and socklen_t.

My code is:

```
  int                   serverPort;
  u_long                serverHost;
  struct sockaddr_in    serverAddress;
  socklen_t             serverAddressLength;
  int                   clientSocket;

  serverPort = 44444;
  serverHost = inet_addr ( "88.198.237.65" );
  serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serverAddress.sin_port =  htons ( serverPort );
  serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htons ( serverHost );
  serverAddressLength = sizeof ( serverAddress );

  clientSocket = socket ( AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 );

  connect ( clientSocket , (sockaddr*)&serverAddress , serverAddressLength )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htons ( serverHost );
```

An IPv4 address is a long, not a short, so `htons` is right out. The data is in network byte order already anyway, so no conversion is needed.

> The **inet_addr**() function converts the Internet host address cp from IPv4 numbers-and-dots notation into binary data in network byte order.

Also:

```
 char                  serverHost;
```

How's it supposed to fit in a `char`?

Comment: wrt to your final question - Luck?!

Comment: Thank a lot, David!
May i ask you, why if I don't apply htons to serverHost on the server side, bind function returns "Cannot assign requested address" and returns "Socket binded successfully" if I _DO_ use htons?

Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Kolyunya: Don't try to understand known buggy code. It will just make you crazy. (Probably, by luck, the `htons` turned it into a zero, which is probably what you really wanted.) Likely the reason you got "Cannot assign request address" is because you tried to `bind` to an address that wasn't assigned to the local system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, David. In fact I do bind socket to the local IP address. Anyways, as I can see "htons" for some reason _IS_ required in "bind" function, right?

Comment: No, it's just changing one bug into a different bug. (`htons` is correct for the port, but it's *never* correct for an IPv4 address.) Fix the bugs I mentioned and post the code that's still giving you trouble. (If this is a Linux box, running `strace` on it is helpful too.)

Comment: So, how do I _CORRECTLY_ bind my socket to the address? I've read, I can use INADDR_ANY constant(?) which returns local IP address. And it _DID_ work for me

Comment: Original question was solved by deleting "htons" and changing char into u_long.

Comment: Binding to INADDR_ANY causes the server to accept connections to any local IP address. (Including 127.0.0.1)